# Is the semantic contract of an interface (OOP) more informative than a function signature (FP)?

Tags: object-oriented, functional-programming, solid

It is said by some that [if you take SOLID principles to their extremes, you end up at functional programming](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/10/solid-the-next-step-is-functional/). I agree with this article but I think that some semantics are lost in the transition from interface/object to function/closure, and I want to know how Functional Programming can mitigate the loss.

From the article:

> Furthermore, if you rigorously apply the Interface Segregation Principle (ISP), you'll understand that you should favour Role Interfaces over Header Interfaces.
>
> If you keep driving your design towards smaller and smaller interfaces, you'll eventually arrive at the ultimate Role Interface: an interface with a single method. This happens to me a lot. Here's an example:

```
public interface IMessageQuery
{
    string Read(int id);
}
```

If I take a dependency on an `IMessageQuery`, part of the *implicit contract* is that calling `Read(id)` will search for and return a message with the given ID.

Compare this to taking a dependency on its equivalent functional signature,  `int -> string`. Without any additional cues, this function could be a simple `ToString()`. If you implemented `IMessageQuery.Read(int id)` with a `ToString()` I may accuse you of being deliberately subversive!

So, what can functional programmers do to preserve the semantics of a well-named interface? Is it conventional to, for example, create a record type with a single member?

```
type MessageQuery = {
    Read: int -> string
}
```

Comment: An OOP interface is more like FP [typeclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class), not a single function.

Comment: You can have too much of a good thing, applying ISP 'rigorously' to end up with 1 method per interface is just going too far.

Comment: @gbjbaanb actually the majority of my interfaces have only one method with many implementations. The more you apply SOLID principles, the more you can see the benefits. But that's off-topic for this question

Comment: @9000 well most FP languages dont have typeclasses but yes there is some relation there

Comment: @jk.: Well, in Haskell, it's type classes, in OCaml you either use a module or a functor, in Clojure you use a protocol. In any case, you don't usually limit your interface analogy to a single function.

Comment: `Without any additional clues`... maybe it is why **the documentation is part of the contract**?

Comment: @SJuan76 it's a fair point - does this mean FP requires more documentation?

Comment: @SJuan76: or, the contract should either be very obvious, or else must be documented unambiguously. Most of the time, there are subtleties in the contract required for correct operation (e.g. consider a `FileStream` object or interface), that is far from self-documentary.

Comment: [Further food for thought](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/05/28/DelegatesAreAnonymousInterfaces/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Telastyn says, comparing the static definitions of functions:

```
public string Read(int id) { /*...*/ }
```

to

```
let read (id:int) = //...
```

You haven't really lost anything going from OOP to FP.

However, this is only part of the story, because functions and interfaces aren't only referred to in their static definitions. They're also *passed around*. So let's say our `MessageQuery` was read by another piece of code, a `MessageProcessor`. Then we have:

```
public void ProcessMessage(int messageId, IMessageQuery messageReader) { /*...*/ }
```

Now we can't *directly* see the method name `IMessageQuery.Read` or its parameter `int id`, but we can get there very easily through our IDE. More generally, the fact that we're passing an `IMessageQuery` rather than just any interface with a method a function from int to string means we're keeping that `id` parameter name metadata associated with this function.

On the other hand, for our functional version we have:

```
let read (id:int) (messageReader : int -> string) = // ...
```

So what have we kept and lost? Well, we still have the parameter name `messageReader`, which probably makes the type name (the equivalent to `IMessageQuery`) unnecessary. But now we've lost the parameter name `id` in our function.

---

There's two main ways around this:

- Firstly, from reading that signature, you can already make a pretty good guess what's going to be going on. By keeping functions short, simple and cohesive and using good naming, you make it a lot easier to intuit or find this information. Once we got into reading the actual function itself, it'd be even simpler.
- Secondly, [it's considered idiomatic design in many functional languages](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-intro/) to create small types to wrap primitives. In this case, the opposite is happening- instead of replacing a type name with a parameter name (`IMessageQuery` to `messageReader`) we can replace a parameter name with a type name. For example, `int` could be wrapped in a type called `Id`:

  ```
  type Id = Id of int
  ```

  Now our `read` signature becomes:

  ```
  let read (id:int) (messageReader : Id -> string) = // ...
  ```

  Which is just as informative as what we had before.

  As a side note, this also provides us some of the compiler protection we had in OOP. Whereas the OOP version ensured we took specifically a `IMessageQuery` rather than just any old `int -> string` function, here we have a similar (but different) protection that we're taking an `Id -> string` rather than just any old `int -> string`.

---

I'd be reluctant to say with 100% confidence that these techniques will always be just as good and informative as having the full information available on an interface, but I think from the above examples, you can say that most of the time, we can probably do just as good a job.

Comment: This is my favourite answer - that FP encourages the use of semantic types

Answer (score 11):

When doing FP I tend to use more specific semantic types.

For example, your method for me would become something like:

```
read: MessageId -> Message
```

This communicates quite a lot more than the OO(/java)-style `ThingDoer.doThing()` style

Comment: +1. In addition, you can encode far more properties into the type system in typed FP languages like Haskell. If that were a haskell type, I would know that it's not doing any IO at all (and thus likely referencing some in-memory mapping of ids to messages somewhere). In OOP languages, I don't have that information - this function could ring up a database as part of calling it.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on why this would communicate *more* than the Java style. What does `read: MessageId -> Message` tell you that `string MessageReader.GetMessage(int messageId)` doesn't?

Comment: @BenAaronson the signal to noise ratio is better. If it's an OO instance method I have no idea what it's doing under the hood, it could have any kind of dependency that's not expressed. As Jack mentions, when you have stronger types, you have more assurances.

Answer (score 10):

> So, what can functional programmers do to preserve the semantics of a well-named interface?

**Use well named functions.**

`IMessageQuery::Read: int -> string` simply becomes `ReadMessageQuery: int -> string` or something similar.

The key thing to note is that names are only contracts in the loosest sense of the word. They only work if you and another programmer infer the same implications from the name, and obey them. Because of this, you can really use *any* name that communicates that implied behavior. OO and functional programming have their names in slightly different places and in slightly different shapes, but their function is the same.

> Is the semantic contract of an interface (OOP) more informative than a function signature (FP)?

Not in this example. As I explained above, a single class/interface with a single function isn't meaningfully more informative than a similarly well named standalone function.

Once you get more than one function/field/property in a class, you can infer more information about them because you can see their relation. It's arguable if that's more informative than standalone functions that take the same/similar parameters or standalone functions organized by namespace or module.

Personally, I don't think that OO is significantly more informative, even in more complex examples.

Comment: What about parameter names?

Comment: @BenAaronson - what about them? Both OO and functional languages let you specify parameter names, so that is a push. I'm just using the type signature shorthand here to be consistent with the question. In a real language it would look something like `ReadMessageQuery id = <code to go fetch based on id>`

Comment: Well if a function takes an interface as a parameter, then calls a method on that interface, the parameter names for the interface method are readily available. If a function takes another function as a parameter, it's not easy to assign parameter names for that passed in function

Comment: Yes, @BenAaronson this is one of the pieces of information that is lost in the function signature. For example in `let consumer (messageQuery : int -> string) = messageQuery 5`, the `id` parameter is just an `int`. I guess one argument is that you should be passing an `Id`, not an `int`. In fact that would make a decent answer in itself.

Comment: @AlexFoxGill Actually I was just in the process of writing up something along those very lines!

Comment: @BenAaronson - ah, I see now. In my experience, the parameter can be pretty easily understood by how the function parameter is used, but you're right that such things are probably more understandable with concrete interfaces.

Comment: The essence of functional programming (vs procedural programming) is that functions can be passed around. A good function name does not help you at all to enforce a contract for a callable parameter. The function name is lost when you pass it around as a variable / parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that a single function can't have a 'semantic contract'.  Consider these laws for `foldr`:

```
foldr f z nil = z
foldr f z (singleton x) = f x z
foldr f z (xn <> ys) = foldr f (foldr f z ys) xn
```

In what sense is that not semantic, or not a contract?  You don't need to define a type for a 'foldrer', especially because `foldr` is uniquely determined by those laws.  You know exactly what it's going to do.

If you want to take in a function of some type, you can do the same thing:

```
-- The first argument `f` must satisfy for all x, y, z
-- > f x x = true
-- > f x y = true and f y x = true implies x = y
-- > f x y = true and f y z = true implies f x z = true
sort :: forall 'a. (a -> a -> bool.t) -> list.t a -> list.t a;
```

You only need to name and capture that type if you need the same contract multiple times:

```
-- Type of functions `f` satisfying, for all x, y, z
-- > f x x = true
-- > f x y = true and f y x = true implies x = y
-- > f x y = true and f y z = true implies f x z = true
type comparison.t 'a = a -> a -> bool.t;
```

The type-checker isn't going to enforce whatever semantics you assign to a type, so making a new type for every contract is just boilerplate.

Comment: I don't think your first point addresses the question - it's a function definition, not a signature. Of course by looking at the implementation of a class or a function you can tell what it does - the question asks can you still preserve the semantics at a level of abstraction (an interface or function signature)

Comment: @AlexFoxGill - it's *not* a function definition, although it does uniquely determine `foldr`.  Hint: the definition of `foldr` has two equations (why?) while the specification given above has three.

Comment: What I mean is that foldr is a function not a function signature.  The laws or definition are not a part of the signature

Answer (score -1):

Pretty much all statically-typed functional languages have a way to alias basic types in a way that requires you to explicitly declare your semantic intent.  Some of the other answers have given examples.  In practice, experienced functional programmers need *very* good reasons to use those wrapper types, because they hurt composability and reusability.

For example, say a client wanted an implementation of a message query that was backed by a list.  In Haskell, the implementation could be as simple as this:

```
messages = ["Message 0", "Message 1", "Message 2"]
messageQuery = (messages !!)
```

Using `newtype Message = Message String` this would be much less straightforward, leaving this implementation looking something like:

```
messages = map Message ["Message 0", "Message 1", "Message 2"]
messageQuery (Id index) = messages !! index
```

That might not seem like a big deal, but you either have to do that type conversion back and forth *everywhere*, or set up a boundary layer in your code where everything above is `Int -> String` then you convert it to `Id -> Message` to pass to the layer below.  Say I wanted to add internationalization, or format it in all caps, or add logging context, or whatever.  Those operations are all dead simple to compose with an `Int -> String`, and annoying with an `Id -> Message`.  It's not that there are never cases where the increased type restrictions are desirable, but the annoyance had better be worth the trade off.

You can use a type *synonym* instead of a wrapper (in Haskell `type` instead of `newtype`), which is much more common and doesn't require the conversions all over the place, but it doesn't provide the static type guarantees either like your OOP version, just a bit of enapsulation.  Type *wrappers* are mostly used where the client isn't expected to manipulate the value at all, just store it and pass it back.  For example, a file handle.

Nothing can prevent a client from being "subversive."  You're just creating hoops to jump through, for every single client.  A simple mock for a common unit test often *requires* weird behavior that doesn't make sense in production.  Your interfaces should be written so they don't care, if at all possible.

Comment: This feels more like a comment on Ben/Daenyth's answers - that you can use semantic types but you don't because of the inconvenience? I didn't downvote you but it's not an answer to this question.

Comment: -1 It would not hurt composability or reusability at all.  If `Id` and `Message` are simple wrappers for `Int` and `String`, it is *trivial* to convert between them.

Comment: Yes, it's trivial, but still annoying to do all over the place.  I've added an example and a little bit describing the difference between usage of type synonyms and wrappers.

Comment: This seems like a size thing. In small projects, these kinds of wrapper types probably aren't that useful anyway. In large projects, it's natural that the boundaries will be a small proportion of the overall code, so doing these types of conversions at the boundary and then passing around wrapped types everywhere else isn't too arduous. Also, like Alex said, I don't see how this is an answer to the question.

Comment: I explained how to do it, then why functional programmers wouldn't do it.  That's an answer, even if it's not the one people wanted.  It has nothing to do with size.  This idea that it's somehow a good thing to intentionally make it more difficult to reuse your code is decidedly an OOP concept.  Creating a product type that adds some value?  All the time.  Creating a type exactly like a widely-used type except you can only use it in one library?  Practically unheard of, except perhaps in FP code that interacts heavily with OOP code, or written by someone mostly familiar with OOP idioms.